# Highlight cell based on another cell being changed

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible, if a value in column D changes (Column D contains wage rates) then highlight in that row cell K. Column K has a formula based on column D?

For example if D4 is updated with new wage rate then highlight K4.

Comment: Of course this is possible :) Have you researched a possible solution? This is a conditional formatting classic

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 - "If D4 is updated with new wage rate" - conditional formatting won't work.

Comment: @BigBen dang, you're right. i was imagining it as an empty cell before. i guess `worksheet_change` will have to do

Comment: How do Column D values change?

Answer (score 1):

This code will color the corresponding cell in Column K if a cell in Column D changes.
The issue with this is if the cell in column D changes again the cell in Column K will not change again.

***Note:*** A worksheet change event will only fire if you put the code in the sheet module concerned.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim RngChnge As Range
Set RngChnge = Columns(4)

    If Not Intersect(RngChnge, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(, 7).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If

End Sub
```